# Rust compilation error for active borrow when acually there isn't any

Tags: rust, lifetime, borrow-checker, ownership

Following snippet fails to compile:

```rust
struct Node {
    i: i32,
    next: Option<Box<Node>>,
}

fn insert(head: &mut Option<Box<Node>>, i: i32) {
    let mut curr = head;

    if let Some(node) = curr {
        if node.i > i {
            curr = &mut node.next;
        }
    }
    
    std::mem::replace(curr, Some(Box::new(Node { i: i, next: None })));
}
```

Here is the error I get:

```
error[E0499]: cannot borrow `*curr` as mutable more than once at a time
  --> src/lib.rs:15:23
   |
9  |     if let Some(node) = curr {
   |                 ---- first mutable borrow occurs here
...
15 |     std::mem::replace(curr, Some(Box::new(Node { i: i, next: None })));
   |                       ^^^^
   |                       |
   |                       second mutable borrow occurs here
   |                       first borrow later used here
```

I am failing to understand the error on line 15. How does `*curr` remain borrowed till line 15 ? Shouldn't the borrow end after the preceding `if let ...` block?

What's even more confusing is that if I remove the inner `if` condition, the code compiles!

```rust
struct Node {
    i: i32,
    next: Option<Box<Node>>,
}

fn insert(head: &mut Option<Box<Node>>, i: i32) {
    let mut curr = head;

    if let Some(node) = curr {
        //if node.i > i {
            curr = &mut node.next;
        //}
    }
    
    std::mem::replace(curr, Some(Box::new(Node { i: i, next: None })));
}
```

Comment: A well-known bug in the borrow checker.

Comment: If you remove the unncessary `curr` variable you'll get a little more information about the lifetimes the compiler infers. https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=5bf9fd993e9bb9e12165a7e244e41e14